# Reporting the average log-probability the model assigns to some examples

Tags: machine-learning, probability, predictive-models, logarithm

I am currently studying *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville. In chapter **5.1.2 The Performance Measure, $P$**, the authors say the following:

> To evaluate the abilities of a machine learning algorithm, we must design a quantitative measure of its performance. Usually this performance measure $P$ is specific to the task $T$ being carried out by the system. For tasks such as classification, classification with missing inputs, and transcription, we often measure the **accuracy** of the model. Accuracy is just the proportion of examples for which the model produces the correct output. We can also obtain equivalent information by measuring the **error rate**, the proportion of examples for which the model produces an incorrect output. We often refer to the error rate as the expected 0-1 loss. The 0-1 loss on a particular example is $0$ if it is correctly classified and $1$ if it is not. For tasks such as density estimation, it does not make sense to measure accuracy, error rate, or any other kind of 0-1 loss. Instead, we must use a different performance metric that gives the model a continuous-values score for each example. The most common approach is to report the average log-probability the model assigns to some examples.

It is this last part that I'm curious about:

> The most common approach is to report the average log-probability the model assigns to some examples.

Just so I am clear on this, can someone please give a mathematical illustration of what this process would look like? I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: perhaps this can help http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss

Comment: @AlejandroCelis But this article doesn't seem to clarify what "average log-probability" is?

Comment: well, the article mentions that "The equations below demonstrate how to calculate log loss for a single observation. When evaluating a model against a dataset, your log loss score is simply the average log loss across all observations.".  So the average log loss is obtained by taking a simple average over all the observations.    You can read about the connection between "loss" and "probability" here for instance https://towardsdatascience.com/log-loss-function-math-explained-5b83cd8d9c83

Comment: @AlejandroCelis Ahh, you're right. This seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you!